# Remove/disable content script from Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After running this code:

```
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      file: 'content.js'
    });
```

is there some way to disabled the content.js script after injecting it into a tab? Is the only way to disable it to close the tab?

I could potentially flip a boolean to stop executing what's in the script, but that's not totally completely disabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute code just once, you can pass it as a string. 
See available params for [chrome.tabs. executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: 'console.log("Hello")'
});
```